# angularjs lifecycle: $onInit not called

Tags: angularjs

the documentation for migration from angularjs 1.5 to 1.6 says "Disabling (by default) the pre-assignment of bindings on controller instances, which helps with support for native ES6 classes." and "Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's $onInit() method, which is guaranteed to always be called after the bindings have been assigned."

I try to do this migration for our project and I observed, that for some of the controllers $onInit doesn't get called. In the official documentation I didn't find anything related to this, but there are some other sources:

https://www.tejusparikh.com/2017/universality-oninit-callback-angularjs.html

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14630

Are there other cases when the $onInit doesn't get called? Is this documented somewhere "more officially"?

Thank you!

Comment: You're saying that they don't get called; you've put console.log's in them and they don't fire? Not behaviour that we've encountered and we have just switched to using $onInit() throughout.

Comment: Yes, they don't get fired for those directive controllers which are used for routes. For (all?) the other directives it seems to get fired.

Comment: Our routing (saved as config.routes.js per directory for example) uses the structure: export default function config($stateProvider) { ... } i.e., no controllers associated to that. If you mean each individual state, importing it then setting as: controller: SomeController, then we have no issues with those working either. Possibly the problem lies somewhere else? Perhaps post an example of your routes?

Answer (score 4):

I have also found that controllers Initialized by ngRoute, $onInit is not called.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if your controller returns an object then the $onInit will not be triggered.

Following a traditional JS IIFE module pattern you could return an object that maps public keys to internal methods, effectively creating a public interface to your privately scoped functions. I left some of this code when converting to a Component with a Controller and found that $onInit was not being called until I removed the "return {};" at the end of the controller function.

I don't know if this is the same cause sanyi9 was dealing with, but it's the same symptom of $onInit not being called even though the rest of the controller executes as expected (and other controllers have functioning $onInit calls).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
controllers.ControllerName = ['$scope', '$rootScope','$timeout',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        $timeout(function () {
            if (!$scope.IsCallOnInit) {
                $scope.$onInit();
            }
        });

        $scope.$onInit = this.$onInit = function () {
            $scope.IsCallOnInit = true;
        }
    }];
```

Comment: That is a very clever workaround! Thanks